# Symfony 2, Sonata User Bundle : Invalid state, originalRoles array is not set

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

When i try to create a new user, with or without role(s) selected i straight have this error :

> Invalid state, originalRoles array is not set

Roles choices are added that way (Not modified, straight from vendor):

```
->add('realRoles', 'sonata_security_roles', array(
                    'label'    => 'form.label_roles',
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'required' => false
                ))
```

And here the code that return the exception (straight from vendor, so probably not a good idea to fix the error here except if it is a real issue).

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function reverseTransform($selectedRoles)
{
    if ($this->originalRoles === null) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Invalid state, originalRoles array is not set');
    }

    list($availableRoles, ) = $this->rolesBuilder->getRoles();

    $hiddenRoles = array_diff($this->originalRoles, $availableRoles);

    return array_merge($selectedRoles, $hiddenRoles);
}
```

Any solutions or hints?

**UPDATE :**

Issue moved to [Github Sonata](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/548) with some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem caused by redefining of constructor in entity extending from `Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser`

To solve this problem, add `parent::construct()` in the child entity.

Comment: This project was long ago but you might be right, in a more recent project i did care about the construct method and didn't face this issue again.